# cgminer Rejected as lowdifficulty

Tags: cgminer

I got an issue with cgminer constantly rejecting shares. How can I fix it?

Here's example rejection (note that Diff jumps - sometimes it's 6/1 sometimes it's 1/1) :

```
[2013-04-09 14:24:05] Rejected fe26cac1 Diff 4/1 GPU 0 (lowdifficulty)
```

Here's the .bat file I use:

```
cgminer --scrypt -o eu-stratum.btcguild.com:3333 -u MyUser -p 123
```

My OS is Win 7 32 bit.

Comment: What is your share difficulty set to in the btcguild settings?

Comment: Under 2 GH/s (I got weak PC here where I try to set it up)

Comment: I just tried 8-16 and 16-32 - both fail with the same result. What's weird is that I have cgminer setup on another PC with much better GPU and it works flawlessly there with difficulty set to 8-16.

Comment: To closevoters:  this question is on topic as per the current FAQ.  If we want it to be off-topic we should clarify the wording there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue also the fix for me was  adding`--scrypt -o` to the beginning so it look like this :

`--scrypt -o stratum+tcp://stratum.scryptguild.com:3333  -u iwantcoins_nick -p nopw --load-balance`

Comment: Also worth trying to tune your other GPU settings, this will increase your hashrate, and hopefully reduce your rejected share rate.